# How does RaphaelJS get inline SVG to work in Firefox 3.6?

Tags: javascript, vector, svg, inline, raphael

I was playing around with RaphaelJS and realized that it gets inline SVG working in Firefox 3.6.22 (at least it [looks like it](http://raphaeljs.com/pie.html), or am I fooled by Firebug...).

As my own SVG does not show up, I was wondering how RaphaelJS accomplishes this feature when [Firefox 3.6 does not support blunt inlining of SVG](http://caniuse.com/#search=inline%20svg). I (briefly) looked at the source and also found [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4420234/inline-svg-in-firefox/4440623#4440623) how inline SVG can work in older Firefox browsers. Still, I am stuck getting this to work for myself (i.e. AJAX-loading SVG and placing it into the DOM).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am going to answer my own question:

1. Raphaël is not really doing anything special (in this case).
2. Thanks to the answers to [my post on the Raphaël Google Group](http://groups.google.com/group/raphaeljs/browse_thread/thread/d4c797b7c2e108c?hl=en-GB) I was pointed in the right direction. "Inline SVG" means "inline with common HTML" (also explained in a [Mozilla blog post](http://hacks.mozilla.org/2010/05/firefox-4-the-html5-parser-inline-svg-speed-and-more/)), so without using XHTML and proper namespacing. My prior understanding was that I could use SVG only via `<object>` or `<embed>` in some browsers (like Safari 4 or Firefox 3.6)... which is wrong.

   I was adding SVG by passing it as an XML string to [jQuery's .html() method](http://jqapi.com/#p=html). This works fine in the current versions of most modern browsers but the method name gives a hint that this might not be the right way if you want to add SVG in a browser that does not support SVG in **html**. So I changed my code and used [document.createElementNS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.createElementNS) to add my SVG directly to the DOM. There is another way to bulk-inject my SVG-XML (as mentioned in the Google groups thread), but I did not have the time to look into it yet.

   So now I got my SVG working in all targeted browsers but the older IEs, which is nice. Sample code:

   ```
   var svgContainer = document.getElementById("svg-container"),
       svgElement = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "svg"),
       g = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "g");
   svgElement.setAttribute("version", "1.1");
   // Add stuff to the group
   svgElement.appendChild(g);
   svgContainer.appendChild(svgElement);
   ```